# HP TC4200 tablet Stylus not working on Unity interface

Tags: unity, 10.10, eeepc, tablet, stylus

I've installed 10.10 Netbook edition on my HP TC4200 tablet PC.  I primarily use it in the slate mode with a stylus and on screen keyboard.

I can use the stylus as a mouse replacement for everything except for selecting the icons on the Unity-Panel and i have to use the Touchpad to select and activate the icons to launch a program from the Unity-Panel. What could be the problem and if you can suggest a fix would be really appreciable.

This is my first time using Ubuntu (or Linux for that matter), therefore, i am not conversant with the Terminal commands.

Kind regards,
Ram

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/670226), and it happens with every tablet I've tried so far.  The problem seems to be that if you move the stylus even one pixel while you're clicking -- and it's almost impossible not to -- then unity thinks you are dragging and scrolls the panel instead.